# knockout.js computed observable immediately disposed, why?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

Here is a very basic example of a computed observable in knockout:

```
let value = 'hello';

const co = ko.computed({
  read: function() { return value; },
  write: function(arg) { value = arg; }
});

console.log(co()); // Outputs 'hello'

co('bye'); // Update the value

console.log(value); // Outputs 'bye'

console.log(co()); // Still outputs 'hello' when value is already set to 'bye'
```

I traced this problem down to finding that the co's status immediately has isDisposed = true, so it was disposed. But why? By whom?

Even if I put a subscription on it right after creating it, it is still immediately disposed and will just not work.

I suppose maybe I have to somehow applyBindings, but I isolated that problem to where I actually do applyBindings (at least at some point). How else could I first set up an ViewModel (as they call it) and then bind it, if this computed gets disposed immediately?

Now if I had made the value an observable too

```
let value = ko.observable('hello');

const co = ko.computed({
  read: function() { return value(); },
  write: function(arg) { value(arg); }
});

console.log(co()); // Outputs 'hello'

co('bye'); // Update the value

console.log(co()); // Outputs 'bye'
```

Then it suddenly works. But that's dumb! If I just want an observable variable I'd use that. Instead I use a computed because it interacts with some system resource, say a database, and write will change the value in the database, and then read should give that value. If the database value changes something might trigger explicitly this computed as dirty to force re-evaluation, that's a problem for later.

Right now I notice that there seems no way to get the evaluation to work at all because it is considered disposed!

Comment: All examples use observables to keep writable computed values.

Comment: Examples on the knockoutjs site use observables to keep internal values of writable computed.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is your exact situation, then you have just re-created a basic observable.  And no computed is necessary at all.  And it's possible we are overthinking it.

As you noticed yourself in the 2nd part of the question.  It works if "value" is observable.  Which to me makes sense, since you are trying to observe any changes to that variable, just with more steps.

The overhead is so small and easy.  I would say just do it, as is consistent with Knockout.  Knockout is relatively dated anyway.  I still use it all the time in legacy apps.  But it's definitely not perfect.  And I've been aiming to replace it with something newer where possible.

It's also possible that ko "subscribe" is more appropriate for your needs than ko "computed".  Since it looks like you are trying to have one thing depend on another.

Comment: What is that "something newer" which doesn't suddenly throw a huge amount of other stuff in? Like come with some massive "state management framework" or even change everything from data binding to VDOM code stuff. 

I have done a lot of internal work with knockout, and I know of *massive* problems with it which would have a relatively easy solution if only one would rewrite the knockout code from scratch in a much simpler way, haha. But nobody has done it. It seems like every alternative is always adding a whole new world of complexity.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Which is why I still have a bunch of knockout.  "Something newer" would be React, etc.  Which yes is a total rewrite and a pain in the butt in its own way.  For me and the company I work at, it's more beneficial to hop on the bandwagon with everyone else for new development.  Sorry I realize this isn't the place to trash KO which has served us well.  But I do think it's fair to say I am looking to retire my KO where possible for big important company projects.  In the future I will keep opinions about the underlying technology out of the discussion.